# Кто и как определяет языковые нормы?

Tags: орфография, грамотная-речь

Читаю дискуссию о написании слова "эсэмэска", о том, что, мол, это — языковая норма. Но при этом никто так не пишет. Так почему тогда это все-таки норма? Кто и по какому принципу их устанавливает? Я понимаю, что сленг, мат и просто безграмотность нормой стать не могут, но как-то общеупотребительные формы вполне могут стать нормой, но не становятся. И "эсэмэска" — типичное тому подтверждение. Выходит, что нормы определяют авторитетные лингвисты просто волевым решением?

Comment: Нет, они монетку бросают! :-)

Comment: В диалектической борьбе противоположностей (лингвисты vs народ)

Comment: stopkran, у меня было такое же предположение))))

Comment: Я бы сказал, что да, это стало общепринятым **произношением**. Но не написанием.

Comment: "Читаю дискуссию о написании слова "эсэмэска". Где читаете?

Comment: "Общеупотребительные формы вполне могут стать нормой, но не становятся."  Например, какие конкретно?

Answer (score 1):

Лингвисты нормы не определяют.
Они их фиксируют. На основании разных наблюдений, исследований, аргументов. 
Да, и частота использования играет какую-то роль, но это далеко не единственный и, видимо, даже не главный критерий. Прежде всего, пожалуй, рассматривается насколько новое слово или вариант (в т.ч. фонетический вариант) соответствует общим тенденциям развития живого языка. 
И бывает, конечно, что "неграмотное" становится с течением времени нормой. 
Но это отдельный разговор...

Answer (score 1):

Сделаю попытку обяснить, почему это норма.

SMS (Short Message Service) стало русской аббревиатурой СМС, а аббревиатуры без гласных читаются по названиям букв в алфавите (в отличие от ДЭЗа или вуза).

Буквы СМС читаются: эс-эм-эс. Русский люд, а московский особливо, любит суффикс "к" - Ленивка, Волхонка, Покровка, Рождественка... скамейка, батарейка.

Эсэмэска просто прогулялась по проторенной дорожке.

Иначе: по традиции словобразования в языке.

Answer (score 0):

Сленг очень часто становится потом частью обычного языка. Многие слова, которыми мы сейчас пользуемся, когда-то были сленгом.

А определяет, пожалуй, само время. Если слово приживается, его со временем заносят в словари.

Answer (score -1):

Существуют понятия "норма" и "узус". Нормы фиксируются правительством, а также рядом заведений типа Института русского языка Российской Академии Наук, СПБГУ и так далее. Узус -- это общепринятое употребление языка, однако оно может отличаться от нормы и быть незафиксированным в словарях. "Эсэмэску" можно отнести к узуальной разговорной речи. Может быть, когда-нибудь это станет нормой, однако норма изменяется медленно и это требует длительного времени.

Comment: Нормы языка не фиксируются правительством. Это по меньше мере некорректно. Кто и на основании чего вообще дал право правительству командовать языком? Правительства приходят и уходят, а язык остается. Что до ученых, в т.ч. из РИЯ, то и они лишь **фиксиоуют** нормы,  - на основании своих исследований и знаний, -. но не устанавливают. **Устанавливать** можно разве что нормы правописания, но и тут скорее вопрос кодификации.

Comment: В лице министерств Образования, Культуры и т.п. нормы языка на письме и фиксируются, и внедряются, и контролируются. На такие вещи монополия государства обязательна. Правительства, конечно, уходят или, точнее, меняются, а институты остаются.